# Java dock a dialog on another dialog

Tags: java, dialog, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created two dialogs simultaniously. Now I want to dock the one dialog to the other. So if one will be moved the other will be moved also.

I have tried to implement a listener, but it does not work, because he will be called after the dialog is closed.

```
public class DialogOne extends TitleAreaDialog {

    public DialogOne(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        setTitle("Dialog One");
    }

    @Override
    public int open() {
        Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DialogTwo dialogTwo = new DialogTwo(getShell());
                dialogTwo.open();
                dialogTwo.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Moved");

                    }
                });

            }
        });
        return super.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setShellStyle(int newShellStyle) {
        super.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
        setBlockOnOpen(false);
    }
}

public class DialogTwo extends TitleAreaDialog {

    private Composite composite;

    public DialogTwo(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        setTitle("Dialog Two");
    }

    @Override
    protected void setShellStyle(int newShellStyle) {
        super.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
        setBlockOnOpen(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        return composite;
    }

    public void addControlListener(ControlListener listener) {
        composite.addControlListener(listener);
    }
}
```

So how I can accomplish to get the bounds from the second dialog and reposition the first one next to the second. Also when the second will be moved.

Comment: Please don't use the "code snippet" feature. It's only meant to be used with JavaScript. I've removed it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to achive my requirments. I figured out, that I can first create the dialog with `dialogTwo.create()`. So I can do what ever I want before the dialog will be opened. In this case I the shell and add a control listener.

```
public class DialogOne extends TitleAreaDialog {

  private Shell dialogShell;

  public DialogOne(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
  }


  @Override
  public void create() {
    super.create();
    setTitle("Dialog One");
    getShell().addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {


      @Override
      public void controlMoved(ControlEvent controlevent) {
        moveDialog(DialogOne.this.getShell());

      }
    });
  }


  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    createSecondDialog();
    return composite;
  }

  private void createSecondDialog() {
    final DialogTwo dialogTwo = new DialogTwo(getShell());
    dialogTwo.create();
    dialogShell = dialogTwo.getShell();
    dialogShell.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {


      @Override
      public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
        moveDialog(dialogShell);

      }
    });

    Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {


      @Override
      public void run() {

        dialogTwo.open();
      }
    });

  }

  protected void moveDialog(Shell shell) {
    Rectangle rightBounds;
    int dialogBorder = 10;
    if (shell.equals(getShell())) {
      rightBounds = shell.getBounds();
      dialogShell.setLocation(rightBounds.width + rightBounds.x + dialogBorder, rightBounds.y);
    } else {
      rightBounds = dialogShell.getBounds();
      Rectangle leftBounds = getShell().getBounds();
      getShell().setLocation(
        rightBounds.x - leftBounds.width - dialogBorder,
        rightBounds.y);
    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void setShellStyle(int newShellStyle) {
    super.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
    setBlockOnOpen(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `dialogTwo.open()` blocks. You can get non-blocking behavior if you add `dialogTwo.setBlockOnOpen(false)` before calling open.

The second thing is: You should add a ControlListener to the shell and not to one of its children. So this should work:

```
            DialogTwo dialogTwo = new DialogTwo(getShell());
            dialogTwo.setBlockOnOpen(false);
            dialogTwo.open();
            dialogTwo.getShell().addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Moved");

                }
            });
```